# Can a veteran martial artist with yellow skin beat Hal Jordan?

Tags: dc, green-lantern

Can a veteran, advanced and experienced human martial artist with yellow skin/body completely defeat Hal Jordan by taking out the ring from his finger first and then proceed to demolish him? It seems that Hal Jordan is pretty much invincible when comparing him to characters out of comic book universe.(Sorry, I am not much of a comic book guy.)

Comment: Why exactly must the man have yellow skin? Your question is unclear; I would suggest you change it to something like "How well does Hal Jordan fight without his ring?".

Comment: I assume you meant that Hal Jordan is “invincible” rather than “invisible.” Feel free to revert if this is incorrect.

Comment: @Gallifreian Because I heard that Green Lanterns are a bit weak to yellow. I mean if the martial artist is not yellow and just normal skin then Hal Jordan with his ring can easily defeat him. But, If that martial artist body skin his yellow then Hal Jordan's ring can maybe be ineffective. So the martial artist might have a chance right?

Comment: @Adamant Yes thx for correcting it.

Comment: @LuckyAli I'm pretty sure that "yellow" refers to the Yellow Rings of Power, aka *Sinestro Corps*, as those are the embodiment of fear, and fear is the counter-agent for willpower, which powers the Green Lantern Corps. It is said somewhere on this site that a Green Lantern must overcome his/her greatest fear every time when using the ring.  A random yellow guy would not be able to defeat Hal *with the ring on*; I'm also sure Hal can fight without the ring too - he's a pilot, they must have some sort of martial arts training, right?

Comment: Here: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/51373/can-anyone-wield-a-green-lantern-ring?rq=1

Comment: @Gallifreian It used to be that GL constructs wouldn't affect yellow things. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_ring_(DC_Comics)#Limitations (See the 4th paragraph) I don't think this is part of current canon

Comment: Would the veteran be vulnerable to a 2 ton truck dropped on him after being levitated above him by a power ring?

Comment: We can't answer a generalized question about who would beat who (Shark vs Gorilla is the term generally thrown around), but as kjw below has proven, we can answer the question of whether Green Lantern is still vulnerable to the color yellow, or if something like that has happened before. :) If you could change your question to that, it would not be closed.

Comment: Answered best here: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/80110. In addition to mentioning the removal of the yellow weakness, this answer covers the apocryphal story mentioned in the answer below. The hypothetical martial artist's color has no bearing at all. More importantly, even when separated from the ring, a Green Lantern is still in control of it. If we're wondering how the GL would fare if his ring wsan't functioning, that comes down to the individual GL's training and skills. Of course, Hal DOES hang around with Batman, so I'm sure he's picked up at least a few tricks...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't have the comic with me so I'll have to update this answer later, but in one issue of Batman, Batman and Robin painted a room and themselves yellow when meeting with the Green Lantern.  For some reason that is slipping my mind right now, Robin attacked him and he was basically defenseless.  Robin almost killed him with a hit to his throat before Batman stepped in.

I think Batman and Robin both qualify as excellent martial artists.  The yellow skin was improvised but essentially meets your criteria.

Comment: Please make me unsee this...

Comment: Here's some pages: https://comicnewbies.com/2014/09/09/batman-paints-a-room-yellow-for-green-lantern/

Comment: @sumelic That's the one.  Thanks!